# Where to send a request , parent component or child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

After a page is split into multiple components, the data of each component is obtained asynchronously, so the request should be initiated by the parent component and then passed to the child component, or the corresponding request sent directly to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to child components using `props`. But for a bigger application managing this would become harder. So, you need to use a state management library such as `Redux` or `MobX`.

Comment: thanks, i have already use the redux, so there is no problem about the way about of passing data.  but there still a question about where to send request. i think child component mounted faster than parent, so  request should send in child component. is that right?

Comment: By request do you mean passing data or an AJAX request?

Comment: an ajax request

Comment: You can have Actions which calls the API and then pass the data to the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective topic. There are various state management libraries like Redux that help solve this problem. You can even use your own personal preference architecture like MVC / MVVM to build your apps.  If you are a beginner then I would suggest you explore first on your own, that will make you understand the pros and cons of the approach you took. Then you can move on to tools like Redux / MobX.

Comment: thanks, i have already use the redux, so there is no problem about the way about of passing data. but there still a question about where to send request. i think child component mounted faster than parent, so request should send in child component. is that right?

Comment: What I usually do is, I create a controller on top of my view which handles all the button clicks and text change etc. I keep all my API calls inside my main model/store and call them from the controller. So basically, it is much cleaner because now I have separated all my API calls from the view. I also have a ViewModel on top of my Controller which contains the business logic. It does not matter where you send the request. It has no impact on performance. It is just how you manage your state and rerenders that impact performance.